# Golang: How to embed interface with different type parameters?

Tags: go, generics, interface

The code gives me error: `DB redeclared`.
Is there any idiomatic way to solve it? Or any work-around?

TIA

```
type a struct {
    DB[int64]
    DB[string]
}

type b interface {
    DB[int64]
    DB[string]
}

type DB[T any] interface {
    GetList(query string) ([]T, error)
}
```

Comment: Field and method names must be unique. You can't embed the same type twice, what would calling a promoted method mean? Which field's method? Or which field would `a.DB` denote?

Comment: I would encourage you to read more about Go generics first and understand the basics

Comment: @MarvinCollins I read https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics and https://go.dev/blog/intro-generics. That's all what I found. But it doesn't explain how the generics works with struct and interface, especially, when/how to use generics in method. Do you have any recommended documents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't embed the same interface, even with different type parameters. Regardless of how it is instantiated, you are trying to promote into the `b` interface two methods with the same name `GetList` *and different signatures* — given by the different instantiations of `DB`.

The situation is similar, although not technically the same, for embedding into a struct. In structs, the name of the embedded field is the name of the type — `DB` —, and a struct can't have two non-blank fields with the same name.

About how to solve this issue, it depends what you want to accomplish.

If you want to convey that "`a` implements `DB` with either type parameter" you can embed `DB[T]` and make `a` itself generic, and restrict `a`'s type parameters:

```
type a[T int64 | string] struct {
    DB[T]
}

// illustrative implementation of the DB[T] interface
// if you embed DB[T] you likely won't use `a` itself as receiver
func (r *a[T]) GetList(query string) ([]T, error) {
    // also generic method
}
```

This is okay because `DB`'s type parameter is constrained to `any`, and `a`'s type parameter is **more** restrictive. This allows you to use `a` in other generic methods, or choose a specific type upon instantiation, but the implementation of `GetList` has to be parametrized too.

Otherwise if you need `a` to have **separated methods** that return `int64` or `string`, you must give it different names.

Finally, you can embed instances of `DB` into two interfaces with different names, and then embed those into `a` instead.

```
type a struct {
    DBStr
    DBInt
}

type DBStr interface {
    DB[string]
}

type DBInt interface {
    DB[int64]
}
```

This way though the top-level selector isn't available because the method names are still the same. The program compiles, but you'll have to explicitly choose which field to call the method on:

```
myA := a{ /* init the two fields */ }

res, err = myA.DBStr.GetList(query)
// res is type []string
// or
res, err = myA.DBInt.GetList(query)
// res is type []int64
```